# how to bootstrap.js confliction with two versions of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a jquery version coming from master page.

```
<script src="~/Content/Bootstrap/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and i have new version of jquery and bootstrap at my view page.

```
<script src="~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/Bootstrap/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var jquery1.11 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

While the problem of confliction between two versions of jquery is solved by using no conflict but the bootstrap.js is throwing error -- `Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher` as it is referring to old jquery version that is `1.6.4`
and on console `$.fn.jquery = "1.6.4"`
How to solve this bootstrap issue?

Comment: Why do you keep two version of Jquery? Remove the oldest one.

Comment: it is coming from the master page i cannot remove it from there as there are some functions live, delegate being used in other pages.

Answer (score 3):

If you change the order the scripts are loaded it should work...

```
<!-- load original jquery -->
<script src="~/Content/Bootstrap/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- scripts run here will use `jQuery` and `$` version 1.6.4 -->

<!-- load new jquery (to be used by bootstrap) -->
<script src="~/Content/Bootstrap/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- load bootstrap, which will use new jquery -->
<script src="~/Content/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- scripts run here will use `jQuery` and `$` version 1.11.3 -->

<!-- give $ back to original jquery -->
<script>var jquery11 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>

<!-- scripts run here will use `jQuery` and `$` version 1.6.4 -->
<!-- scripts can access version 1.11.3 with jquery11 -->
```

Comment: Well, then you have to change all `$()` reference to `jquery1.11()`

Comment: oops i was writing bootstrap before new version that's the mistake

Comment: btw - `jquery1.11` is not a valid variable name